# Compiling error determining software version

Tags: c, makefile, compiler-errors, fftw

I'm trying to compile this scientific software and running make gives problems that I've been stuck on for days. The error is
`Error: Unable to determine fftw version.`

The specific compilation line that's giving me issue is
`cc -c -static -m64 -O1     -fcommon -DGIT_SNANA_VERSION=\""v11_05d-43-gce493d51"\"  -I/path/to/directory/cfitsio-4.2.0/include ../src/sntools_output.c`

Been debugging this back and forth with no success so far. I'm on a cluster machine so I need to locally install a lot of softwares. I install gsl, cfitsio, etc. successfully and also installed fftw. Running fftw-wisdom doesn't give me errors for one. Typing `which fftw-wisdom` points to my local installation. So far I tried adding -L flags, checking libfftw3.a exists, and adding relevant paths. None of them worked. Any ideas on what I could do here?

Typing `make` inside `src` directory gives me

```
(cd ../obj; \
cc -c -static -m64 -O1     -fcommon -DGIT_SNANA_VERSION=\""v11_05d-48-g4f35048a"\"  -I//global/homes/u/user/local/cfitsio-4.2.0//include ../src/sntools_output.c )
Error: Unable to determine fftw version.
make: *** [Makefile:907: ../obj/sntools_output.o] Error 1
```

Typing `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` gives me the following output.

```
/global/homes/u/user/local/fftw/lib:/global/homes/u/user/local/gsl/lib:/global/common/software/dessn/perlmutter/desdm/eups/packages/Linux64/cfitsio/3.370+1/lib:/global/common/software/dessn/perlmutter/desdm/eups/packages/Linux64/openblas/0.3.10+0/lib:/opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk/Linux_x86_64/22.7/math_libs/11.7/lib64:/opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk/Linux_x86_64/22.7/cuda/11.7/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk/Linux_x86_64/22.7/cuda/11.7/extras/Debugger/lib64:/opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk/Linux_x86_64/22.7/cuda/11.7/nvvm/lib64:/opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk/Linux_x86_64/22.7/cuda/11.7/lib64:/opt/cray/pe/papi/7.0.0.1/lib64:/opt/cray/pe/gcc/11.2.0/snos/lib64:/opt/cray/libfabric/1.15.2.0/lib64:/global/common/software/dessn/perlmutter/desdm/eups/packages/Linux64/fftw/3.3.2+5/lib
```

So my local fftw installation should be accessible. Typing `which fftw-wisdom` yields `/global/homes/u/user/local/fftw/bin/fftw-wisdom`. I do realize that there are two fftw installed (one locally and one at

`/global/common/software/dessn/perlmutter/desdm/eups/packages/Linux64/fftw/3.3.2+5/lib`

I tried changing LD_LIBRARY_PATH to only include one of the two but still get the same error.

Since the error isn't not being able to locate fftw but the problem lies with the version, I'm not sure what is causing the problem. The code I am trying to compile is a couple of dozen lines of headers followed by functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

// #include "sntools.h"
#include "sndata.h"
#include "sntools_output.h"

// include the package-specific code(s) here.
#ifdef USE_HBOOK
#include "sntools_output_hbook.c"
#endif

#ifdef USE_ROOT
#include "sntools_output_root.c"
#endif

#ifdef USE_TEXT
#include "sntools_output_text.c"
#endif

#ifdef USE_MARZ
#include "sntools_output_marz.c"
#endif
```

Here's a snippet of the header. I don't see anything that particularly stands out.

Comment: The compiler isn't generating that error. That's something from the Makefile, configure script, or possibly a static assert in the code. So my guess is that you are trying to compile some code you downloaded from the Internet. What are you trying to compile and where did you get it from?

Comment: The code is from https://github.com/RickKessler/SNANA/blob/master/src/Makefile.
Line 906. It's for making supernova simulation.

Comment: You need to dig at least one level deeper. What is happening in `sntools_output.c`?

Comment: Okay, I'm looking through github.com/RickKessler/SNANA/blob/master/src/sntools.c. All I see are list of include header and functions. Is there something specific I should be looking for? I've only coded in Python for the last five years and forgot most of my C... I'm quite confused by what kind of problems would lead to "Error: Unable to determine fftw version." If it couldn't find fftw, shouldn't the error message be something along the line of "fftw library not found"?

Comment: The first thing to do is show us, via editing the question, the actual command you typed and the exact output you got.  Cut and paste it (you should omit the middle, successful build commands) into your question and format it as a code block.  Context is critical and when you extract just a single error message without any context we can't figure out what is failing.

Comment: I see there is a new commit on github. Problem resolved?

Comment: Yes. I got it resolved. Is there anything further I should do with this post? Any feature for marking this question as resolved?